Did Popper ever mention Rand and vice versa?
I’ve read a lot of Karl Popper’s writings and a fair amount of Ayn Rand’s.
It seems odd that two of the most influential philosophers of the 20th century never talk about each other or address each other’s points. Both worked on political philosophy and epistemology, and both would have complemented each other’s understanding.
Is there any evidence that these two were aware of one another, knew about the other’s ideas (at least in broad strokes), or even addressed them?
I’m not looking for a discussion of the (de)merits of either philosopher.

I am afraid not, but a Popperian Nyquist wrote a book on Rand's philosophy, see Seddon's critical review. You may also find Shoshiashvili's Why was Ayn Rand marginalized by America's leading Capitalist Thinkers interesting. It analyzes Rand's reception by contemporary philosophers generally. For example, Nozick "appreciated Rand's work and often cited her" even though he did not agree with her "moral foundations of capitalism."
